# AngularJS sorting up/down icons aren't visible

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried to sort the table data on click event of table headers. But unable to see the up/down icon accordingly.
Codepen of my code is [here](https://codepen.io/Zaraa/pen/eVeVEY)

Please let me know where I'm doing wrong.

Here is my Code

AngularJS

```
var myApp = angular.module("myModule", []);
myApp.controller("sortctrl", function ($scope) {
var students = [{
    "name": "Shirl MacCallister",
    "class": 7,
    "section": "B",
    "rollno": 203,
    "gender": "Female"
}, {
    "name": "Florance Skilbeck",
    "class": 6,
    "section": "A",
    "rollno": 240,
    "gender": "Female"
}];

 it'll work
$scope.students = students;
$scope.sortcolumn = "rollno";
$scope.reversesort = false;
$scope.sortdata = function (column) {
    $scope.reversesort = ($scope.sortcolumn == column) ? !$scope.reversesort : false;
    $scope.sortcolumn = column;
}
$scope.getsortclass = function (column) {
    if ($scope.sortcolumn == column) {
        return $scope.reversesort ? '.arrow-down' : '.arrow-up'
    }
    return '';
} });
```

HTML

```
 <body ng-app="myModule">
<div class="container" ng-controller="sortctrl">
    <br><br>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr role="button" style="cursor: pointer">
            <th ng-click="sortdata('name')">Name<div ng-class="getsortclass('name')"></div></th>
            <th ng-click="sortdata('rollno')">Roll No.<div ng-class="getsortclass.('rollno')"></div></th>
            <th ng-click="sortdata('class')">Class<div ng-class="getsortclass.('class')"></div></th>
            <th ng-click="sortdata('section')">Section<div ng-class="getsortclass.('section')"></div></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="student in students | orderBy:sortcolumn:reversesort" >
            <td>{{ student.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ student.rollno }}</td>
            <td>{{ student.class }}</td>
            <td>{{ student.section }}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
```

And please don't mark this question as duplicate, I haven't found the solution for my problem on S/O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working version: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yvPvEB

You need to remove

- the dots on the `getsortclass` calls (`getsortclass('')`, not `getsortclass.('')`)
- the dots before the class names in `getsortclass` (`'arrow-down'`, not `'.arrow-down'`)